# sql-alchemy sqlite database problems, it is not allow me to create foreign keys

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

here is my code:

```
class usersTable(db.Model):
    userid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fname = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    lname = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.LargeBinary, unique=True, nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.LargeBinary, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.LargeBinary, nullable=False)
    joined = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
    subuser = db.relationship('subuserTable', backref='userid')

class subuserTable(db.Model):
    userid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('usersTable.userid'))
    subid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.LargeBinary, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.LargeBinary, nullable=False)
    fname = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    lname = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
```

The problem is that whenever i try to run:

```
db.create_all()
```

I run into this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'subuser_table.userid' could not find table 'usersTable' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'userid'
```

I know that there is a `usersTable` table, and also the `userid` column is there, so why is it giving me this much grief?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```py
userid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('usersTable.userid'))
```

to

```py
userid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users_table.userid'))
```

From Flask SQLAlchemy [docs](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/#declaring-models):

Some parts that are required in SQLAlchemy are optional in Flask-SQLAlchemy. For instance, the table name is automatically set for you unless overridden. It’s derived from the class name converted to lowercase and with “CamelCase” converted to “camel_case”. To override the table name, set the **tablename** class attribute.

Comment: That done it!  Thanks alot!  So can you explain why I have to name it differently?

Comment: wait i see why, even when using camel case sqlite creates the table as users_table

Comment: Yes, You are letting Flask SQLAlchemy to choose the names. You can override it by the tablename attribute

Comment: i was waiting for the delay.  It makes me wait 10 minutes